# Why does my freezer suddenly have more frost than it did?

Tags: refrigerator

My freezer that attached to my fridge has all of a sudden and lot of frost on the top and on the items in it. Why would it has a lot of frost and what's the easiest way to get rid of the frost.

Comment: A deteriorated seal opening some air flow would be the most likely reason. See if your door closes airtight.

Comment: Someone might have left the door open. See if this repeats before doing anything.

Comment: Could too much things in the freezer cause a lot of frost?

Comment: Having a freezer stuffed full might prevent the fan from circulating air necessary for the frost free operation.

Comment: I cleaned out my freezer today and remove the frost. So I will see if that helps.

Comment: Summertime brings more humidity, which turns to frost in a freezer.

Answer (score 1):

Could be that the defrost drain line is plugged (water frozen in the line).

Answer (score 0):

Could be the defrost cycle system is broken. This includes the timer for starting the system, the thermistor for stopping it, the heating element, the water drain.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to a bad gasket, letting in humid air. See if you can easily slide a piece of paper through any edges of the door. If you can, then you may need to replace the gaskets. Usually not too hard to do, but (at least for my Kenmore) relatively expensive parts. The gaskets come preassembled to match specific model length/height.